# Type 'CustomMap' is missing the following properties from type 'Map<Element>'

Tags: typescript, google-maps

I have created a custom **KmlLayer** class to which I had to add in a value of the custom map class to the `map` property similar to this guide here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Like so:

```
import { CustomMap } from "./CustomMap";
// src: string = "http://cales-map.webitects.com/HOLC_KML.kmz";
const customMap = new CustomMap("map");

export class CustomKmlLayer {
  private kmlMap: google.maps.KmlLayer;

  // here is where I am initializing the KML Layer of the map
  constructor(src: string) {
    this.kmlMap = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: src,
      map: customMap,
    });
  }

  kmlLayerMethod() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.kmlMap, "click", () => {
      console.log("KML Layer event clicked!");
    });
  }
}
```

Above I imported the `CustomMap` class from here:

```
// Instructions to every other class
// on how they can be an argument to
// 'addMarker', even though right now

import { Data } from "./Data";

// there is only one 'Data' class
export interface Mappable {
  Latitude: number;
  Longitude: number;
  markerContent(): string;
}

export class CustomMap {
  private googleMap: google.maps.Map;

  // here is where I am initializing the map to be upon boot up
  constructor(divId: string) {
    this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(divId), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: {
        lat: 36.778259,
        lng: -119.417931,
      },
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      styles: [...],
    });
  }

  // this method gets applied later inside `index.ts` when
  // user clicks on 'Oakland, CA' from dropdown
  addOakland(): void {
    const oak = (this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map"),
      {
        zoom: 13,
        center: {
          lat: 37.804363,
          lng: -122.271111,
        },
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        styles: [...],
      }
    ));
  }

  // this method gets applied later inside `index.ts` when
  // user clicks on 'San Francisco, CA' from dropdown
  addSanFran(): void {
    this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: {
        lat: 37.733795,
        lng: -122.446747,
      },
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      styles: [...],
    });
  }

  // makes the red dots happen including the listener
  // for clicking the dots and seeing their label
  addCircleMarker(mappable: Mappable): void {
    const circleMarker = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 1,
      map: this.googleMap,
      clickable: true,
      center: {
        lat: mappable.Latitude,
        lng: mappable.Longitude,
      },
      radius: 120,
    });

    const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: mappable.markerContent(),
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(circleMarker, "click", () => {
      infoWindow.setPosition(circleMarker.getCenter());

      infoWindow.open(this.googleMap);
    });
  }
}
```

However, with this implementation, I get the following error:

> Type 'CustomMap' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Map': addListener, fitBounds, getBounds, getCenter, and 31
> more.ts(2740) kml.d.ts(18, 9): The expected type comes from property
> 'map' which is declared here on type 'KmlLayerOptions'

When I click on `Map` inside my `CustomMap` class, I see the type definition file with those properties, but those properties are now missing when I import and instantiate the `CustomMap` class?

I really need these to work as separate classes.

If anyone wants to try and clone the boilerplate and see if you can reproduce:
https://github.com/ldco2016/mappy

I added it as a method:

```
addKmlLayer(): void {
    this.kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: "http://my-maps.com/HOLC_KML.kmz",
      map: this.googleMap,
    });
  }
```

but nothing is displaying.

Comment: It seems some code is missing to be able to debug this. Do you have more of the stacktrace available?

Comment: @JustinPoehnelt, thank you for looking into this. There is no stacktrace as this is an error directly from TypeScript in my code editor. I will however, add the full `CustomMap.ts` file, hopefully that can help you help me.

Comment: Where is CustomMap being passed that requires the google.maps.Map interface? The error seems to be that customMap.googleMap should be passed instead of the customMap instance.

Comment: @JustinPoehnelt, the `this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map()` is being passed into the `constructor()` of the `CustomMap` class inside of `CustomMap.ts`. I provided a Github repo if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I think I need to see more to be able to debug.

Comment: Seems to work in https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ldco2016/mappy (minus the key issues)?

Comment: @JustinPoehnelt, its the `CustomKmlLayer` class that I am having the trouble with. What you shared  on CodeSandBox does not have that logic included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe typescript wants your `CustomMap` to extend `google.maps.Map`. But since you seem to be using composition, I guess you'll have to proxy all those methods.

```
new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: src,
      map: customMap, // customMap should implement google.maps.Map
    });
```

Alternatively, you could make `googleMap` property public (or add a getter for it) and use it during the layer instantiation:

```
new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: src,
      map: customMap.googleMap,
    });
```

But you'll have to re-instantiate the layer every time the value of the `googleMap` property changes (after adding Oakland or SanFran etc).

I hope this can help you find the right solution.

Comment: @D Pro, proxy the methods? What do you mean?

Comment: @D Pro, how would you do a `class CustomMap implements Map {}` with Google Maps? It is not a library that can be imported into a file.

Comment: @Daniel have extended my answer, hoping it will be of help